# FolderBrowserDialog fails to open in Debug mode

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, folderbrowserdialog

Hi need your help cause I have this problem that I really don't know how to solve... when I am in debug mode the program get stuck here (see pic)

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
StringBuilder srb = new StringBuilder();
FolderBrowserDialog
sfd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

DialogResult drl =  sfd.ShowDialog();
                    String folderWhereIsave = "";
if (drl == DialogResult.OK)
{
folderWhereIsave = sfd.SelectedPath;
}
```

[image]
The folder browser dialog doesn't pop up. When I launch the .exe from the project folder I don't have this problem...Do you know why?!?
thanks for your help

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. It is **critical** that the [mcve] code is in **text** not an image.

Comment: Possibly it's waiting to build a list of network drives, or other slow resource. It may be useful to check `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: You'll *have* to refactor your code into separate classes, simply to make it more understandable. This will also prevent code in one part of the file affecting fields/variables used by a different part